# Combining two ActiveRecord queries with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination

I have two active record queries:

```
feedbacks = Activity.where(subject_type: Feedback.name).select{ |f| f.subject.application == @application }
activities = Activity.where(subject: @application)
                    .order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
                    .per(10) + feedbacks
```

I feel like there must be a better way to combine the results of these two queries. Also, pagination isn't going to work right since `feedbacks` could return `n` records.

If I added pagination to both queries, then I could get double the items than I actually want to display.

**Edit:** Here's an attempt which seems to be working, though - not pretty:

```
activities = Activity.where('subject_id = ? OR subject_type = ?', @application.id, Feedback.name)
  .order(created_at: :desc)
  .page(params[:page])
  .per(20).select { |record|
    if record.subject_type == Feedback.name
      record.subject.application == @application
    else
      true
    end
  }
```

Comment: is subject a polymorphic association?

Comment: @NicolasMaloeuvre yes, it is

Comment: Is your pagination handled by Kaminari? In Kaminari, you can set the default pagination in the config file (see their documentation; you need to install a separate config file). I am not sure if this solves all of your problem, but it should take care of the totals per page.

Comment: Your last example is not the same as your first one, it is not checking `(subject_id == @application.id AND subject_type == @application.type) || subject_type == "Feedback"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Activity Model :

```
belongs_to :feedback, -> { where(activities: {subject_type: 'Feedback'}) }, foreign_key: 'subject_id'
```

then in your controller :

```
feedbacks = Activity.includes(:feedback).where(feedbacks:{application:@application})
other_activities = Activity.where(subject: @application)
matching_ids = (feedbacks.map(&:id)+other_activities.map(&:id))
activities = Activity.where(id:matching_ids).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
```

This solution is not really scalable, you should make quite a complex query because of two conditions based on polymorphic associations